# Swift: GET request with application/octet-stream in response

Tags: swift, audio, avplayer

I have the following `GET` request (short version for explaining) for playing a sound:

```
func playSound() {

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://someWebsite/api/sounds/play?id=1") else {fatalError() }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        request.setValue(uuid, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-AUTH-Device")
        request.setValue(appid, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-AUTH-AppID")
        request.setValue(someToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-AUTH-Token")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, _ in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                (200...599).contains(httpResponse.statusCode),
                let mediaData = data else {
                    return
            }
            print(mediaData)
        }
        .resume()
}
```

Hereby, in `mediaData` I receive some data and all I know is that it has to be a stream of type `(Content-Type: application/octet-stream)`. So I'm stuck in the understanding of how to decode/handle this media data to be playable in AVPlayer or other players.
Also, I've tried to add URL and headers in AVPlayer without get request but it didn't work and I'm not sure what approach to use here. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: NSSound(data): Pass any Data object, and if it is a valid sound file, you will get an NSSound object. Doesn't matter much what format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:
https://github.com/neekeetab/CachingPlayerItem

And in code:

```
   ...URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, _ in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                (200...599).contains(httpResponse.statusCode),
                let mediaData = data else {
                    return
            }
            self.playSound(data: mediaData)
        }
        .resume()
}

func playSound(data: Data) {
    let playerItem = CachingPlayerItem.init(data: data, mimeType: "audio/mpeg", fileExtension: ".mp3")
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    guard let player = player else { return }
    player.play()
}
```